# C# Filling a 2D array with objects from a txt file at specific positions

Tags: c#

Im trying to fill a 2D array with a txt file from my computer.

I have tried doing this in two different ways but i have not gotten either to work.

1. Save objects position number in the file using the following code.

   ```
                for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++)
                {
                    if (cpp[row, col] == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (cpp[row, col] == null) continue;
                        save.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", row + 1, cpp[row, col].RegNumber, cpp[row, col].VehicleTypes, cpp[row, col].TimeOfArrival));
                    }
                }
            }
   ```

Second way i have tried is to save the file with the empty lines aswell.

```
 foreach (var temp in cpp)
            {
                if (temp == null) save.WriteLine("");
                if (temp == null) continue;
               save.WriteLine("{{0},{1},{2}", temp.RegNumber, temp.VehicleTypes, temp.TimeOfArrival);
            }
```

I have gotten nowhere with the load function and i would appreciate any help i can get with this. I need to load the file in to my 2D array and the objects have to be assigned to the same position it was before.

The only code i have for the load function is this.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("CarParkPrague.txt");
            var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
            {
                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    var values = line.Split(",");
                    Enum.TryParse(values[1], out VehicleType type);
                    var time = DateTime.Parse(values[2]);
                    vehicles.Add(new Vehicle(values[0], type, time)); 
                    
                }
            }
```

Text file line  example = AAA111,CAR,2020-10-11 14:19:04
Or with the position saved = 1,AAA111,CAR,2020-10-11 14:19:04
Can be either, which ever is easiest.

This is a test method that works but it saves the vehicles on first best available spot in the array so its not quite right. The text file is in this case saved without a position number. And looks like the first example above.

```
static void LoadTestFile() //Loads the array using the test file which is filled with examples.
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("testfile.txt");
        var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var values = line.Split(",");
            Enum.TryParse(values[1], out VehicleType type);
            var time = DateTime.Parse(values[2]);
            vehicles.Add(new Vehicle(values[0], type, time));
        }

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                if (counter >= vehicles.Count)
                    break;

                if (cpp[i, 0] != null)
                {
                    if (cpp[i, 0].VehicleTypes == VehicleType.CAR)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (vehicles[counter].VehicleTypes == VehicleType.CAR)
                {
                    cpp[i, j] = vehicles[counter++];
                }
                else
                {
                    cpp[i, j] = vehicles[counter++];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loading function will crash if you have empty lines, so I can't quite believe it works to read a file with blank lines on. The big problem with it though is that it doesn't do anything if it encounters a blank line when really it should be putting a blank (null) vehicle at that position in the list

Save blank lines if the vehicle is null, and also save dates in a fixed format:

```
        foreach (var temp in cpp)
        {
            if (temp == null) 
                save.WriteLine();
            else
                save.WriteLine("{{0},{1},{2}", temp.RegNumber, temp.VehicleTypes, temp.TimeOfArrival.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
        }
```

Load, catering for blank lines by putting no vehicle (null) in that position:

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("CarParkPrague.txt");
        var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
        
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            { 
                vehicles.Add(null);
                continue;
            }
            var values = line.Split(",");
            Enum.TryParse(values[1], out VehicleType type); //should really test this with an if
            var time = DateTime.ParseExact(values[2], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null);
            vehicles.Add(new Vehicle(values[0], type, time)); 
                
        }
    }
```

Hopefully you can see how your "if the parking space is empty the vehicle is null and this becomes a blank line during save" is translated back upon load to "if the line is blank then the space is marked as empty by putting a null vehicle there"

Edit; as you seem to have a fixed number of parking spaces and are using null to represent emptiness, having a collection like a List, which dynamically sizes to fit the contents is perhaps not ideal. Switch to using an array that represents the size of the car park:

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("CarParkPrague.txt");
    var vehicles = new Vehicle[100];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length && i < vehicles.Length; i++)
    {
        var line = lines[i];

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            continue;
        
        var values = line.Split(",");
        Enum.TryParse(values[1], out VehicleType type); //should really test this with an if
        var time = DateTime.ParseExact(values[2], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null);
        vehicles[i] = new Vehicle(values[0], type, time); 
            
    }
}
```

Don't forget that the `vehicles` in the load method should be assigned to the same variable that `cpp` in the save method represents. Really, you ought to use the same class wide variable in both methods

Comment: Alternatively, just write the column number as well as the row number.

Comment: I'm not sure it helps; the data column layout is always the same

Comment: Yes i realize that and i am grateful! The problem of loading the file into the array still exists unfortunately. With that change in to my existing load function it just added the first vehicle on the list and not the rest.

Comment: How many lines does the file have? You posted a single line file sample but if that's your entire file then naturally you'll only have one line and your loop only runs once. If you want to have a 1 line file and 100 parking spaces and this 99 spaces that are null you should consider switching the list to an array of vehicle and cease populating the array when you run out of file lines. Or use notepad to add 99 blank lines to the end of your file

Comment: Also, you aren't loading the file into an array; you're loading it into a list. It might seem like I'm being pedantic but an array and a list are very different things, and if you use "array" when you should use "list" furring a conversation with another software engineer you'll cause a lot of confusion

Comment: I've added an edit for you to think about re storing the Vehicles in an array instead, in relation to the above-above comment

Comment: The file has 200 lines. 

I know the difference between an array and a list. I have a static 2d array that the text file is going to be loaded in to. I have made it work now and will post solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with something that's entirely trivial - mirror the save and load methods. The only thing you really need to add is the dimensions of the array:

```
var rowCount = cpp.GetLength(0);
var colCount = cpp.GetLength(1);

save.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0},{1}", rowCount, colCount));
for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
  for (var col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
  {
    if (cpp[row, col] == null) save.WriteLine();
    else save.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0},{1},{2}", cpp[row, col].RegNumber, cpp[row, col].VehicleTypes, cpp[row, col].TimeOfArrival));
  }
}
```

To read this very straight-forward file format, do the same thing in reverse:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("CarParkPrague.txt"))
{
  var dimensions = sr.ReadLine()?.Split(',');

  if (dimensions == null 
      || !int.TryParse(dimensions[0], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var rowCount) 
      || !int.TryParse(dimensions[1], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var colCount)
     )
    throw new Exception("Invalid dimensions.");

  var cpp = new Vehicle[rowCount, colCount];

  for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
  {
    for (var col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
    {
      if (!(sr.ReadLine() is {} line) throw new Exception("Unexpected end of file.");
      if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line)) continue;

      var values = line.Split(",");
      if (!Enum.TryParse(values[1], out var vehicleType)) throw new Exception($"Unexpected vehicle type '{values[1]}'.");
      if (!DateTime.TryParse(values[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTime) throw new Exception($"Invalid time '{values[2]}'.");

      cpp[row, col] = new Vehicle(values[0], type, time); 
    }
  }
}
```

There's plenty of ways to optimize this, but there's little reason to bother if the resulting file is just a few kilobytes (or even tens of kilobytes).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. This is a solution that works for my project. Save file and load in to the 2d array.

```
 static void SaveFile() //Saves the current array using streamwriter.
    {
        Console.Clear();
        StreamWriter save = new StreamWriter("CarParkPrague.txt");
        using (save)
        {
     
            foreach (var temp in cpp)
            {
                if (temp == null) save.WriteLine();
                else
                save.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", temp.RegNumber, temp.VehicleTypes, temp.TimeOfArrival);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("File saved succesfully");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------");
    }


static void LoadFile() //Loads the array using the saved file.
    {
        try
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("CarParkPrague.txt");
            var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
            {
                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    {
                        vehicles.Add(null);
                        continue;
                    }
                    var values = line.Split(",");
                    Enum.TryParse(values[1], out VehicleType type);
                    var time = DateTime.Parse(values[2]);
                    vehicles.Add(new Vehicle(values[0], type, time)); 
                    
                }
            }
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {

                    if (vehicles[counter] == null)
                    {
                        cpp[i, j] = vehicles[counter++];
                    }
                   else if (vehicles[counter] != null)
                    {
                        cpp[i, j] = vehicles[counter++];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.WriteLine("File could not be found. Please make sure there is a file named (CarParkPrague.txt) in your folder.");
        }
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("File have been loaded succesfully");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
```